# Unity Dropdown Z-position over gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have got a dropdown which when is clicked, the menu goes over another gameobjects with a sprite renderer and a text Component. No matter where I set the Z-pos of the Dropdown to, the text below always covers the dropdown menu.

Comment: We need to see your code to be able you help you out bud

Answer (score 0):

You don't mix `SpriteRenderer` with Unity's UI System. Use SpriteRenderer only where it necessary. For example, if you need the image Object to have `Rigidbody` or collide with other images then use `SpriteRenderer`.

If you don't need `Rigidbody` and Collision, use Unity's `Image` or `RawImage` components to display your image. This should solve your render sorting problem if you arrange them in the right order.

Now, if you still need `SpriteRenderer` then attach [`SortingGroup`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rendering.SortingGroup.html) to **all** the GameObjects involved. You can use [`SortingGroup`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rendering.SortingGroup.html) to explicitly change which GameObject is on the front or back.